# ValidateAntiForgery Token in Asp.Net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Need help validating RequestVerificationToken in Asp.Net MVC application.

When trying to impersonate a User,the verification is failing due to mismatch in form and cookie token(Impersonate user gets added to the cookie during Impersonation).So how should this scenario be handled?

Comment: You should probably show the code you have come to so far.

Comment: Make sure you have the correct machine keys configurations